# Drop down menu not appear correctly

Tags: html, css

I am try to make drop down menu but i don't know why when `ul` hover than drop down `li` not appear correctly i have use z-index and also use position relative.Please check this on top menu.

**Css**

```
#menu > ul  > li:hover ul {
 display:inline;
   }
#menu ul li ul{
position:relative;
display:none;
list-style: none;
margin:0px;
width:200px;
z-index:1000;}
```

**Html**

```
<div id="menu">
<div class="home-icn">
    <a href="<?php echo $home; ?>"><i class="icon-home"></i></a>
</div>
<ul >
   <li><a id="print_menu" href="">Printing</a>
         <ul id="drop_menu_f">
         <li><a>Business Cards</a></li>
         <li><a>Brochure</a></li>
         <li><a>Door Hangers</a></li>
         <li><a>Envelopes</a></li>
         <li><a>Flyers</a></li>
         <li><a>Invoice Books</a></li>
         <li><a>Magnet Cards</a></li>
         <li><a>Note Pads</a></li>
         <li><a>Post Cards</a></li>
         <li><a>Plastic Cards</a></li>
         <li><a>Posters</a></li>
         <li><a>Presentation Folders</a></li>
          </ul>
         </li>
     </ul>
   </div>
```

[image: Hover li]

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/hnTyB/1/

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li>My Menu
            <ul>
                <li>thing</li>
                <li>thing2</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I made a js fiddle of what it appears you are trying to do. Copying your css exactly, this seems to work for me. Could it be your html and css don't correctly match?

Comment: Thanks i know about that.my side my html structure and also css correct.Check i have been add html code in question.check it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/e3ZtR/ I made a new fiddle with your html and it still appears to work. This leads me to think that there is some other css or javascript in your code that is causing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I checked out your site [soniprinting.com](http://soniprinting.com) (saw the URL in your screenshot) and it looks like you are missing a `z-index` from your `#menu ul`.

Add a `z-index` greater than those of the slideshow, and you should be able to see your dropdown just fine.